Is there a matrix with rational entries similar to a given matrix?
I am working on the following problem.
Is there a matrix $A$ with rational entries similar to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0\\0 & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$? What about $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0\\0 & -\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$?
Now, in the first case, there is no such matrix because its trace would be $2 \sqrt{2}$. But in the second case, all I can answer is "maybe". The trace is zero, so I can't rule it out. I know the eigenvalues will be $\pm \sqrt{2}$, but this doesn't tell me anything. Is there a systematic way to solve this? Can I "undiagonalize" a matrix in such a way that I can tell directly whether this matrix $A$ exists or not?
Any help is appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

@GerryMyerson The dreaded rational canonical form. Thank you. I do get how to do it now.

In the second case, it's equivalent to find a matrix $A$ with rational entries such that $A^2=2I$ (because $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, it must be the minimal polynomial of $A$, hence $A$ can be diagonalized over $\mathbb C$ with $\pm \sqrt 2$ as eigenvalues). It's not hard to construct one:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
One approach is to consider $A$ as the matrix corresponding to $\sqrt 2$ multiplication for the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. This is a systematic way to construct matrices that satisfy an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.
Another approach is to make sure the trace of $A$ is $0$ and $\det$ of $A$ is $-2$, so it's natural to put $0$ on the main diagonal, and factor $2$ to be on the other entries.

The phrase we are looking for is companion matrix.

@GerryMyerson Right, but I'm more into number fields, so forgot to mention it.

@Justauser  Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify the part about multiplication by $\sqrt{2}$? Do you mean that given a basis $1, \sqrt{2}$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ you need to come up with a matrix that represents multiplication by $\sqrt{2}$? If so, how do you find it besides constructing it like you did?

@user123456 yes, that's exactly what I mean. For the basis ${e_1=1, e_2=\sqrt 2}$, $\sqrt{2}e_1=\sqrt{2} = e_2 = 0\cdot e_1+1\cdot e_2, \sqrt{2}e_2=2=2\cdot e_1+0\cdot e_2$, so the two columns are $(0, 1)^t$ and $(2, 0)^t$.

@Justauser I see. Thank you very much.
